# How to name variables with units?

Tags: java, variables

**Example:**

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

This would lead to something like `String name = person.getName();`
This is straight forward and I know what kind of variable this is.

But what about:

```
public class MovingObject{
    private int mass;

    public int getMass(){
        return mass;
    }
}
```

This leads to `int massOfMovingobject = object.getMass();`

**Question:** How can I add the unit to the code so I actually know what I am dealing with ? Should I name it like `massInKg`, even though it doesn't look good ? One idea would be to add it to documentation but what about the case when it's a global variable within a class ?

Comment: Do you have a lot of different 'unit's in your program? If they are fundamental types, you can even make a struct for them (like `DateTime`/`TimeSpan`, but now for `Mass`/`Velocity`). Then those are always in their base unit (eg. kg).

Comment: It is not so much about how many units but rather where I use them. I want an easy way to know what kind of unit it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best NOT to use units in variable names, unless they are used for converting.

As a guideline:

- In all business logic, only use metric code (or any default standard units system)
- Only when displaying something or outputting something to a reading friendly file, use the unit requested by the user and use specific conversion functions for this (e.g. in a self-made class).

So in your case MovingObject should use the 'default'  unit system, and when you need to display it in a GUI control you can say e.g.

```
SomeGuiControl.Value = UnitConverter.Kilo2Pounds(object.getMass());
```

Comment: This is the best solution to prevent confusion, otherwise later on you could be attempting to remember if the mass you are currently dealing with was in pound or KG

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to store the variable in one unit which is the same to all object for example in your case in Kilogram and then add methods to retrieve different units:

```
public class MovingObject{
    private int mass; //in KG

    public int getMassinKG(){
        return mass;
    }
    public int getMassinPound(){
        //do the calculation
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another method to expand on Pooya's suggestion, if you want to keep the method naming the same but use parameters to change the type:

```
public class MovingObject{
    private int mass; //in KG
    private MassType defaultType;

    public int getMass(){
        return getMass(defaultType);
    }
    public int getMass(MassType type){
        switch(type){
            case Pound:
                //Do calc
                break;
            default:
                return mass;
        }
    }
}

public enum MassType{
    KG,
    Pound
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return an array instead of the integer value alone.
Your array would be something like:

```
public HashMap getMass()
{
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<int, String>();
  map.put("mass", mass);
  map.put("unit", unit);
  return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a mass object that has a variety of constructors accommodating the input signatures you need and then provide the methods to calculate the unit conversion of the object.

extending one step further we could consider momentum and velocity and create a Newtonian object.

Unit conversion is a good fundamental example because it is technically a scalier transformation. here is some more code. Starting off from what @Pooya provided.

```
public class MovingObject{
    private double mass; //in KG
    private double velocity; //in KG
    public MovingObject(){
        this.mass = 0;
        this.velocity = 0;
    }
    public double getMassinKG(){
        double mass = this.mass;
        return mass;
    }
    public double getVelocityKG(){
        double velocity = this.velocity;
        return velocity;
    }
    public void setMassinKG(double s){
        this.mass=s;
    }
    public void setVelocityKG(double s){
        this.velocity=s;
    }
    public String momentum(){
        return(String(this.mass*this.velocity)+"kg m/s");
    }
    public String massInPounds(){
       return(String(this.mass*2.20462)+"pounds");
    }
    public String massInKilograms(){
       return(String(this.mass)+"kilograms");
    }
    public String velocityInMetersPerSecond(){
       return(String(this.velocity)+"meters per second");
    }
    public String velocityInFeetPerSecond(){
       return(String(this.velocity*3.2808)+"feet per second");
    }
}
```

Notice a couple things here. First the methods with the name get return data stored as members of the class. Also setters are voids that take updated member values as arguments. Finally the methods for formatted outputs can be named as you feel suits you.

Happy Programming : )